# Node JS SQL Google cloud platform - Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, google-app-engine

Hola amigos necesito hacer una apliación hosteada en **google cloud platform** , está misma la estoy haciendo en NodeJs, y pues para hacer el cuento MUY corto, google te permite manejar sql a partir de instancias que creas en sus servicios de **gcloud** , ellos te dan una ip y puedes accecar a ella mediante **ssh** o un terminal que ellos te proveen. Mi pregunta es? alguiens sabe como puedo conectarme con SQL y Express a un de estas dbs, ya tengo todo, pero no consigo conectarme, seguí los pasos de la documentación. Pero tambien he encontrado fuentes en donde parecen montar un simple conexión y solo usan la ip que les proporciona google. Alguien podría orientarme un poco? ,

Este es mi código de conexión:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const {db}  = require('./keys');

/*
prueba2
*/ 
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS
  });
  
    connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Connected as thread id: ' + connection.threadId);
    });
  
    module.exports = connection;


/*
prueba 1

const pool = mysql.createPool(db);

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err; // not connected!
  
    // Use the connection
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (error, results, fields) {
      // When done with the connection, release it.
      connection.release();
  
      // Handle error after the release.
      if (error) throw error;
      if(connection) console.log('connect timeout: '+connection.config.connectTimeout+' / idthread : '+connection.threadId)
      
      // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
    });
  });


  //promisify pool query añade promesas
pool.query = promisify(pool.query);

module.exports =  pool;

*/
```

la prueba 1 y los keys son las mismas variables de entorno, pero ninguna conecta, ambas me mandan un:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

literal me he basado en la documentación y en el siguiente ejemplo.
fuentes:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-sql
https://medium.com/@austinhale/building-a-node-api-with-express-and-google-cloud-sql-9bda260b040f

!NOTA: este problema surgió porque no activaba el proxy , que bien està referido en la documentaciòn y por eso me mandaba.

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
>   como si no tuviese internet, pero era porque google me negaba el acceso, por no seguir sus practicas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya sé porque pasaba, me hacía falta iniciar el proxy de conexión que pide gcloud `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="[YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]"=tcp:3306` , con eso terminal ya pude conectarme.